# What is this UI element called where a list of options are are presented for selection

Tags: selection, multi-selection

I'm working on this UI element to replace the dropdown and multiple select UI rendered by browsers for the `select` HTML tag. I would like to show a list of options where users can click on each option to select/unselect it. Depending on the presence of `multiple` attribute, users should be able to select one or more items from this list of options. What is the name of such an UI element?

[image]

These are the goals I'm trying to achieve:

- Should be able to see all the options, hence dropdown is not desirable
- Should let users select one or multiple options
- Selected option(s) should be highlighted
- Should see the options inlined, similar to when `display: inline-block` is set.
- Should not present the options in a grid because the option names can be of varying length

Comment: As @Seth Warburton has already mentioned in his answer below, radio buttons and checkboxes can serve the functional requirements. However, my question is not how to do this, rather what is this UI element called.

Answer (score 5):

You should focus first on the functional requirements, not the visual appearance as that's easily changed with CSS. There's two specific input elements that provide exactly the functionality you describe, radio and checkbox. Radios are for selecting one option from many in a list, while checkboxes are for selecting one or several options in a list.

From the W3C spec:

Radio: ‘The input element with a type attribute whose value is "radio" represents a selection of one item from a list of items (a radio button).’ https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html

Checkbox: ’The input element with a type attribute whose value is "checkbox" represents a state or option that can be toggled.’ https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Styling up `<input type=checkbox>` or `<input type=radio>` to look like your example is trivial, requiring only a few lines of css.

If you only want to describe the *visual aspect* of your illustration ‘group of buttons’ might be a good option, but I think that is misleading as these elements won't function like buttons. Overall I'd say ‘Checkboxes styled like buttons’ is probably the most accurate description to use here.

Comment: +1 for the W3C reference to radio and check box. However I would never recommend changing the styling to a button - remember form follows function, it's not the other way around and you are likely to introduce some confusion.

Comment: @Splatz I didn't recommend it, but if the design calls for that then I think this is the best approach as it is semantically correct, and certainly a better choice tham `<element type=select>` if it's not going to look like a select element. `<button>` and `<a>` would also be the wrong choice as the intent is not to _do something_ or _go somehere_. I agree with you though, if my requirements called for such functionality I'd use radio and checkbox elements with native styling.

Comment: Everything you say is correct apart from "if the design calls for it". Even if it is semantically correct in the html, it is certainly not correct from a visual perspective, e.g it will look like a button when styled on the screen - so it is going to imply a certain expectation in the users mind.

Comment: @SethWarburton Thanks for bringing up the W3C docs. You're right, check boxes or radio buttons do serve the functional requirements here. But how do I name this altered representation if I wanted to communicate the idea to someone. I could say something like "I want a list of options which are actually radio buttons, but they should be inlined and the selected items should be highlighted and etc. etc." Communication would be simpler If there was a one word or one phrase name for this.

Comment: @Splatz, you're correct in general, but in this particular case the OP's example certainly looks as a button, it will work as a button and users will expect it to be a button. So is kind of a [*Duck Test*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test): If it walks like a duck...

Comment: @Raiyan what's wrong with just calling them checkboxes and radios and allowing them to appear like checkboxes and radios? Users already understand these functions; they are already learned. Perhaps ask yourself why, if an element should behave like a checkbox, would I make it look like a button? Personally, I wouldn't. That can only reduce user understanding, surely? From your description, these elements won't _behave_ anything like a button.

Comment: @SethWarburton as mentioned earlier, I would like to use a single word or single phrase name for this UI element if there exists one. If 'checkbox' and 'radio button' is all we have, then I need to clearly spell out the detail of how I would like thhe appearance to be customized.

Comment: @Raiyan If you only want to describe the visual aspect of your illustration ‘group of buttons’ might be the best option. That's not the same as ‘button group’ though, that as that name is already by a UI element that actually is a group of buttons. I'd say ‘Checkboxes styled like buttons’ is probably a  more accurate description though.

Comment: @SethWarburton I really like this suggestion, "checkboxes styled like buttons". If you can edit your answer to include this, I will mark yours as the correct answer. Thanks for the discussion, enjoyed it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Button Group would be the most commonly used term, in my experience, for what you are describing and illustrating.

https://www.google.com/search?q=button+group

Comment: I think you are incorrect - a button group is group of buttons which are being used to trigger some feature/function. What @Raiyan is showing are buttons being used to to select an option, e.g. essentially behaving like radio buttons.

Comment: @Splatz - similar to bold/italics/underline, or left/center/right justification in word processors. Button groups are commonly used is similar ways to radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach. When you have less than 5 options for users to select from, radio buttons or checkboxes are a good idea. I think you can design this interface similar to the wireframe and the front end developer will know what to use.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons inside a group are called "toggle buttons". I don't think the list has a standard name, though. Perhaps call it "toggle button group"?